# Ошибка при выводе переменной из БД Mysql помогите разобраться

Tags: mysql

> Notice: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in T:c.php on line
>   42

В чём смысл этой ошибки и как сделать, чтобы её не было?

Comment: Похоже, что у вас не объявлена константа. Должно быть что-то типа:

    define("id", 1);

А вообще, хорошо бы на код взглянуть

Comment: Мне че-то кажется, что при объявлении переменной забыли указать доллар в начале.

Без кода что-то сложно понять.

Comment: SQL-запрос в студию

Answer (score 1):

Ой, ёй. Да вы что? Какие объявления констант? Такие ошибки возникают вследствие невнимательности php-писателей. Например:

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`= '" . $param[id] . "' ";
```

Будет генерировать ошибку. Правильно вот так:

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`= '" . $param['id'] . "' ";
```

Обратите внимание на кавычки при указании индекса массива.